# Find a pattern at certain location in a String and replace it with something else in Java

Tags: java, string

I’m facing a weird problem that I cant resolve for some reason. 
If I have this String: “aaaa aa”
And the pattern is: “aa”
So there is 3 places that match that pattern: (aa)(aa)( aa)
I want to change the pattern at specific location (let’s say at the second position) with something else, let’s say this String: “bbb”.

So the final result will be: “aabbb aa”.

What is the simplest way to solve this? Without any special collection or special classes.

Comment: Is it the exact pattern like "aa"? If so, did you have a look at the string methods like `indexOf()` and `substring()`?

Comment: You should give better sample data.  What would happen with e.g. `a aa`?  Would that become `a bb`, or `b ba` ?

Comment: There are actually 4 places in "aaaa aa" matching the pattern "aa"

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a formal regex pattern matcher, and then iterate the input string, looking for `aa` matches.  When we hit the *second* match, then do a substitution of `aa` for `bb`, otherwise just substitute with `aa`, the original value.

```
String input = "aaaa aa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("aa");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

int num = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    String replace = num == 1 ? "bbb" : "aa";
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replace);
    ++num;
}

matcher.appendTail(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());

aabbb aa
```

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class has an `indexOf` method. This method comes in two variants: One where you just specify the needle (the string you want to search), and the method returns the position of the first character in the haystack (the string you are searching) which matches your pattern.

The second variant takes two parameters: The pattern, and the position at which to start.

So, you can do something like this:

```
void replaceSecondOccurrence(String haystack, String needle, String replacement) {
    int occurenceToReplace = 2;
    int pos = -1;
    while (true) {
        pos = haystack.indexOf(needle, pos + 1);
        if (pos == -1) {
            // There is no second occurence. Just return the haystack.
            return haystack;
        }
        if (--occurenceToReplace == 0) return
            haystack.substring(0, pos) +
            replacement +
            haystack.substring(pos + needle.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a little issue with your answer because in `aaaa aa`, the second occurence is actually `a'aa'a aa`. You don't have the expected result. You can check this to test : https://ideone.com/fpT1kx